# Microsoft Access SQL Index

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT OrderLine.ItemNum 
FROM OrderLine
CREATE INDEX ItemIndex1
ON OrderLine (ItemNum)
```

I am suppose to create an Index named `ItemIndex1` on the `ItemNum` field in the `OrderLine` table. I would try running the code but a syntax error FROM clause pops up. I am very confused as to where the error is coming from.

Comment: MS Access or MySQL ? Both are different RDBMS. Please clarify the specific RDBMS you are using

Comment: Please do not paraphrase error messages.  Show the *exact* error.